# Electron: Firebase and Facebook authentication?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, electron

I'm trying to provide additional authentication for user within an app. With email/password auth already implemented, I wanted to add Facebook/ Google authentication as well.

I've tried with `firebaseui`:

```
const ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());
ui.start(selector, {
  callbacks: {
    signInSuccessWithAuthResult(authResult) {
      that.handleAuthentication(authResult);
      return false;
    },
  },
  credentialHelper: firebaseui.auth.CredentialHelper.NONE,
  signInFlow: 'redirect',
  signInOptions: [
    {
      provider: firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
    },
    {
      provider: firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
    },
    {
      provider: firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
    },
  ],
});
```

While the UI is rendered correctly in the passed `selector`, I cannot open Google/ Facebook authentication as it brings this message:

> This operation is not supported in the environment this application is running on. "location.protocol" must be http, https or chrome-extension and web storage must be enabled.

This is correct, since `location.protocol` is equal to `file:`.

My question is - how can I make it possible to use Facebook/ Google auth within an Electron app?

Comment: Any luck with a browser window from within an Electron app just for this purpose?

Comment: @AbhijitSrivastava Unfortunately no, but what I did is created a simple website for auth purpose, and connected the app with it using websockets.

Comment: Okay thanks, I hope someday google includes that.

Answer (score 2):

Firebase Authentication for web isn't supported in this way for desktop applications.  The web SDK is intended to work for browser clients, where the user can be redirected into a web page that performs the third party authentication.  This isn't so easy for desktop javascript (Electron) apps that are not browsers.  You are free to try to obtain an authentication token somehow on your own, but the client SDK isn't going to be able to help you with that.

Comment: Can I somehow open a browser window from within an Electron app  just for this purpose?

Comment: I don't know, I've never worked with election before.

Comment: I've just come across this, that should help you out. https://medium.com/firebase-developers/using-firebase-in-electron-tips-and-tricks-24ac5b44bf5a